# Allocating a 2d integer array in C

Tags: c, memory

I'm trying to dynamically allocate a 2D INT array in C in order to return a transposed matrix, I've done several research on the topic, and it should work this way, however I keep struggling with the program.

I tried it many different ways now (offset, pointer arithmetic), I didn't find a fix for the problem.

I'm either getting trash values or the program crashes (no seg fault, error code crash).

I'm also loooking for a proper version to allocate the memory, I've seen several versions on stackoverflow, the one I would preferrably like to use, is allocating pointer space and the integer space afterwards (the one I'm trying to use in the example below).

```
   // Convert a matrix to it's transposed version. Returns a two dimensional array (pointer)
int **getTransposedMatrix(int *matrix, int dimension_h, int dimension_w){
    int **transposedMatrix = (int **) malloc(dimension_w * sizeof(int*));

    for(int row=0; row<dimension_w; row++){
        transposedMatrix[row] = (int*) malloc(dimension_w * sizeof(int));
    }

    for(int row=0; row<dimension_h; row++){
        for(int column=0; column<dimension_w; column++){
            transposedMatrix[column][row] = *(matrix + row * dimension_w + column);
         printf("%d ", transposedMatrix + (row * dimension_w + column));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return **transposedMatrix;
}
```

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: When allocating you use `dimension_w` for allocating both dimentsions. One dimentsion should be `dimension_h`

Comment: That's because it should return the transposed Matrix, also tried that as well though.

Comment: Understand `int**` has absolutely nothing to do with any array or 2D array. It is simply a *pointer-to-pointer-to* `int`. (that is a single pointer that points to a block of pointers) For each of the pointers in the block, you can assign the address of a block holding multiple `int` values to simulate a 2D array.

Comment: Even the transposed array should use both values.

Comment: If transposed should it be `transposedMatrix[row] = (int*) malloc(dimension_h * sizeof(int));` e.g. `w` rows by `h` columns?

Comment: The return statement is wrong `return **transposedMatrix;` This returns the element in the top left corner.

Comment: Why does `matrix` have a different type `int*` to `transposedMatrix` with `int**`.

Comment: Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: matrix argumeng isn't dynamically allocated, I'm using pointer arithmetic on it, and it was working, I would love to use index brackets though e.g. matrix[row][column] if that was possible, will provide further info later.

Answer (score 1):

I would not bother with a "2D array" such as the one you are setting up, where you're allocating the rows separately. Below is my version which uses a single array and calculates offsets into it accordingly.

```
int *getTransposedMatrix(int *matrix, int dimension_w, int dimension_h)
{
    int *transposed = malloc(dimension_w * dimension_h * sizeof(int));
    for (int row = 0; row < dimension_h; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < dimension_w; col++) {
            transposed[col * dimension_h + row] = matrix[row * dimension_w + col];
        }
    }
    return transposed;
}
```

[ideone with some test examples](https://ideone.com/Loed9l)

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I'd rather have a solution for a seperate allocation, I know how to do the solo pointer one :)

Comment: In that case your original code is correct, but simply change the return statement to: `return transposedMatrix;`. However, I must point out, that unless you are working with very big matrices and you need to effectively move rows around a lot, this way of allocating the space serves no purpose. EDIT: And you do not need to cast `malloc()`. EDIT2: And your print statement should simply be: `printf("%d", transposedMatrix[column][row]);`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @vmt :) I typically cast my memory allocations, I think it's a good practice, also the [column][row] syntax only works when working with that kind of allocation right? I'm not sure, but I'll definitely look into pointer arithmetic using brackets one more time, thanks again! :)

Comment: when you cast it to an `int**`, defererencing once you get `int*` and twice, `int`. Also, casting your allocations in C is completely unnecessary because the cast from `void*` is implicit. Furthermore, it can hide the fact that you may not have included stdlib.h because of implicit declarations. Implicit declarations no longer have return type int, that is in >= c99, but in practice the compiler issues a warning. Even barring all that, in general it is considered a bad practice.